# iOS like web UI

Tags: ios, html

I have seen several interesting web page UIs for mobile devices, that look like an iOS device and can't figure out, how can I achieve similar look and feel (navigation bars, scrolling, zooming, fullscreen or even instant displaying of new page after clicking one of the tabs in toolbar). Could you please post some resources or techniques required to built these?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google has turned up the following link which may do what you need - http://modmyi.com/forums/web-apps/637-iphone-web-page-template.html.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at:

- [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/)
- [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There are several frameworks designed specifically for this. You can take a look at, for example, [jQTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com) and [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Twitter Bootstrap compatible them](http://codecanyon.net/item/ios-bootstrap/3336617)e I found when looking for the same thing.

It looks more comprehensive than the isite.zip linked to in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a bootstrap lover you can try my bootstrap iOS look theme:
http://codecanyon.net/item/ios-bootstrap/3336617

Is updated to the latest bootstrap version (3.0).