# iPhone/iPad GUI simulation

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS like web UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243745/ios-like-web-ui)

I am writing a mobile application. I am using a lot of Jquery, to simulate Iphone GUI.
For example, when you press "edit" appears access block signal. Pressing on them they rotate, and appear delete button.
I did it in Jquery, I am thinking... there's something ready?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you're asking. But you can simulate your "app" (webapp? Unclear) in the iOS simulator. For this you will need to download Xcode on your Mac.

Comment: It's a webapp, I am using JQuery to simulate iPhone/iPad GUI. I asked here, to know if there's something ready.

Comment: Yes, the iOS simulator, part of the Xcode bundle, please download that and use the iOS simulator's Safari application to open your webapp

Comment: I think he means that he's simulating the existing iOS GUI with JavaScript. And now he needs to know whether there are readily made components / plugins which have iOS GUI look&feel.

Comment: In that case I think you'll agree the question is somewhat difficult to tell what is being asked.

Comment: Zvona, understood what is was asking.